# valgrind finds implausible number of invalid writes and reads

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, valgrind

New to valgrind, I am trying to understand why valgrind finds a very large number of invalid writes and reads in one of my C programs. It starts by reporting an invalid write for a function call where the calling pointer to an array, and the array itself, have, I think, been assigned appropriate memory in main. More puzzlingly, it goes on to object to numerous lines in this function where declared doubles are is assigned values.

My C program refines (ie improves) against experimental data a model of the crossbridge cycle of muscle (the cycle of events where tiny protein motors repeatedly interact with filaments of another protein to produce force and movement). The program proceeds by simulated annealing based on the downhill simplex method, the required functions being taken from Numerical Recipes in C.

Each model is defined by 19 parameters, x[1] to x[19]. Memory is allocated to this array in main by first declaring x as a pointer to a double, and then creating an array numbering from 1 to 19.

```
double *x;
x=dvector(1,19);
```

The 19 parameters are then assigned values, initially from guesses and later using an algorithm based on the previous history:

```
for (j=1;j<=19;j++)
{
    x[j]=initial_guess;
}
```

The pointer to the x array is then passed to a function scoremodel which tests the mechanical properties of the model in several ways, each producing a score and a weighted average score y is passed back to main at line 629:

```
y=scoremodel(x);
```

where the declaration of scoremodel on line 932 of my program is

```
double scoremodel(double *x)
```

(I also tried

```
double scoremodel(double x[])
```

but the results with valgrind were the same)

Main then works out from the previous results and the downhill simplex/simulated annealing algorithms what new model should be tested next.

With the great help I received from Mark Setchell after my last post to Stack Overflow, I have now been able to compile my program with gcc-4.9 and the –fopenmp flag, so that I can run it with OpenMP on my MacPro operating with Yosemite OS x 10.10.5). It runs without crashing or hanging. The properties and scores for the majority of the successive models are perfectly sensible and taking these alone the program does refine the starting model appreciably. But weirdly, about one-fifth of the models have absurd properties and very poor scores.

I invoked the current release of valgrind to detect memory errors in a shorter test version of my program called refinemadpmodelinc2 with the command

```
 valgrind-3.12.0/bin/valgrind --leak-check=yes ${HOME}/bin  /refinemadpmodelinc2 inc2_49 model3 model4 0 0.9 20 ../../tls/kappaFHStrunc
```

Valgrind reports that the first error in the program occurs at the line where I declare the function scoremodel.

```
Invalid write of size 8
==33173==    at 0x100001F71: scoremodel (refinemadpmodelinc2.c:932)
==33173==    by 0x100001D8A: main (refinemadpmodelinc2.c:629)
==33173==  Address 0x1045029a8 is on thread 1's stack
==33173==  in frame #0, created by scoremodel (refinemadpmodelinc2.c:932)
```

I take the invalid write of size 8 is caused by me trying to write a double or a pointer to unavailable memory since their sizes are both 8 bytes on my computer. But I don’t understand what is wrong with my function call.

The next hundred lines in the function, nearly all declaration of variables, are passed by valgrind but from line 1109 to line 1203 every non-blank line is considered to be an invalid write of size 8, despite most of these lines being just simple assignments eg

```
exppower=395.9;
```

(when exppower has already been declared as a double). My hunch is that although I have made an error in calling the function scoremodel and upsetting valgrind, these lines must surely be OK. Your help in educating me into the mysteries of valgrind would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead explaining what you think your code does, post actual code in a [mcve]!

Comment: The first index is `0` in C, so `for (j=1;j<=19;j++)` should be `for (j = 0; j < 19; j++)`.

Comment: The only way we'll be able to help is if you show the code.  Valgrind doesn't lie — your code has problems, whether you're aware of it or not.  But there's nothing we can do to help diagnose what Valgrind's said is wrong without the code.  Mind you, line numbers like 629 and 932 are going to complicate things — they're not line numbers you normally see in an MCVE ([MCVE]), being too big to qualify as 'minimal'.  You will need to look hard at how to reduce the code to the bare minimum that reveals the problem.

Comment: In my experience, the "My code can't be that bad!" response to Valgrind or Purify or any other memory checking tool is usually wrong.  Because **"Oh yes it can!"**

Comment: In my experience, the "My code can't be that bad!" response, afer debug, is "You were right - its was worse" :).

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that Valgrind is wrong in this case.

Older versions of "Numerical Recipes" use the Fortran convention for arrays going from 1 to **size** inclusive, allocating an extra, unused element in C and C++. The latest version of the book (third edition, C++ only) has done away with all of this 1-based array stuff (though it's still far from a shining example of how to write C++). However, this is still a pitfall if you mix Numerical Recipes and any form of more conventional C or C++ using 0-based arrays.

Comment: I was grateful for your comments. To find out why valgrind objects to my function call I could easily simplify the program and give you the code. But to understand why my program produces the occasional really poor model, I think it would be impossible to produce a sufficiently truncated code as the scoremodel calls three very long functions which have to deal with solving differential equations on the fly.

Comment: Paul may well have solved my problem. Numerical Recipes in C has been my bible for many years, as it is so lucid and gives clear mathematical backgrounds. Although I have used GSL functions in my work, I find its manual rather impenetrable.  

I am shell-shocked to realise I shouldn’t be using 1-based arrays. But now Paul has pointed this out, I can see that if valgrind assumes that any array must be 0-based, that it will think that x[19], hasn’t been assigned memory.

Could I clarify whether my use of dvector to produce 1-based arrays is illegal under ANSI or just strongly discouraged?

Comment: I will now edit my program to convert my arrays to 0-based and hope that the problems have gone away. I will let you know the result. Many thanks to @Paul.